# Array not being shown in ArrayAdapter when using ASyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using Jsoup to get song names as strings from my website. I want these songs to be shown in an ArrayAdapter. The songs are stored in an ArrayList data type which is what the ArrayAdapter needs as a parameter. The song names are all properly obtained using Jsoup, however the code to display the contents of an ArrayList where the song names are stored does not update the UI accordingly.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
public class AppHome extends AppCompatActivity implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    TextView texx;
    ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    private int i;

    AsyncTask<?,?,?> runningTask;

    String[] attributeList = {"song1", "song2", "song3", "song4", "song5", "song6", "song7", "song8", "song9", "song10", "song11", "song12", "song13", "song14", "song15", "song16", "song17", "song18", "song19", "song20", "song21", "song22", "song23", "song24", "song25", "song26", "song27", "song28", "song29", "song30", "song31", "song32", "song33", "song34", "song35", "song36", "song37", "song38", "song39", "song40"};
    String[] obtainedSongNamesFromAsyncTask = new String[40];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_home);
        texx = findViewById(R.id.text1);

        runningTask = new doit();
        runningTask.execute();

    }


    private final class doit extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params)
        {
            try
            {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://screenscrape4top40.000webhostapp.com/").userAgent("Mozilla/(Windows NT 6.1)").get();
//                Elements firstSong = doc.select("a[id=song1]");
//                String firstSongString = firstSong.text();
//                Log.d("jsoupTag", firstSongString);
                // TODO 1. loop through every element in array
                // TODO 2. Create new string by concatenating the .select() contents (pre & post)
                // TODO 3. Add to wrapper class array
                for (int i = 0; i != attributeList.length; i++)
                {
                    String s = "a[id=" + attributeList[i] + "]";
                    Elements currentSong = doc.select(s);
                    String currentSongTextOnly = currentSong.text();
                    aList.add(currentSongTextOnly);
                }
                Log.d("jsoupTag", Arrays.toString(aList.toArray()));
                // Outputs: [ROSES, BLINDING LIGHTS, THE BOX, LONELY, PHYSICAL, DON'T START NOW, SAY SO, RAIN, INTENTIONS, GODZILLA, BOYFRIEND, NO TIME TO DIE, ADORE YOU, DANCE MONKEY, BETTER OFF WITHOUT YOU, YOU SHOULD BE SAD, IN YOUR EYES, STUPID LOVE, DEATH BED, FALLING, SUPALONELY, BLUEBERRY FAYGO, AFTER HOURS, TO DIE FOR, BEFORE YOU GO, CITY OF ANGELS, WHAT A MAN GOTTA DO, KNOW YOUR WORTH, OWN IT, SOMEONE YOU LOVED, TEQUILA, BOSS BITCH, NO JUDGEMENT, FLOWERS, BIRTHDAY, SUNDAY BEST, SCORPION, THE TAKE, WAR, PLAY PLAY]
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(AppHome.this, R.layout.item, R.id.helloText, aList);

            SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer = findViewById(R.id.frame);


            registerForContextMenu(flingContainer);


            flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            flingContainer.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
                @Override
                public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
                    // this is the simplest way to delete an object from the Adapter (/AdapterView)
                    Log.d("LIST", "removed object!");
                    aList.remove(0);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                    //Do something on the left!
                    //You also have access to the original object.
                    //If you want to use it just cast it (String) dataObject
                    Toast.makeText(AppHome.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                    Toast.makeText(AppHome.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {
                    // Ask for more data here
                    aList.add("XML ".concat(String.valueOf(i)));
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.d("LIST", "notified");
                    i++;
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(float scrollProgressPercent) {
                }
            });

        }
    }


    public void showPopup (View v){
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        popup.inflate(R.menu.dropdown_menu1);
        popup.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick (MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Item 1 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.item2:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Item 2 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.item3:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Item 3 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.item4:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Item 4 clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set Adapter inside of runOnUiThread

```
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    });
```

and check if the array contain values in it. Hopes this may solve your problem